# Hamburger Icon on MasterDetailPage not moving along with the drawer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Im a Xamarin.Forms newbie.

I used this guide to make the toolbar invisible: https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

I also have the changed NavigationPage embedded inside a MasterDetail view.
But after making the toolbar transparent, the Hamburger icon stopped moving to the right side when i open the drawer, instead, it stays on the left, behind the drawer view, like this:

[image]

Because i dont understand much of how Xamarin.Forms work, but im kind of being pressed on to finish the app, i dont really know where to start tinkering with the code.

My renderers and classes are the same as in the tutorial which i used. 
and my HomePage is the detail of the MasterDetail.

This is the renderer for the navigationPage:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MobileCpNavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace MoblieCP.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        IPageController PageController => Element as IPageController;
        MobileCpNavigationPage CustomNavigationPage => Element as MobileCpNavigationPage;

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            CustomNavigationPage.IgnoreLayoutChange = true;
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            CustomNavigationPage.IgnoreLayoutChange = false;

            int containerHeight = b - t;

            PageController.ContainerArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, Context.FromPixels(r - l), Context.FromPixels(containerHeight));

            for (var i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
            {
                Android.Views.View child = GetChildAt(i);

                if (child is Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                child.Layout(0, 0, r, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the extended NavigationPage for the renderer

```
namespace MoblieCP.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MobileCpNavigationPage : NavigationPage
    {
        public MobileCpNavigationPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        public MobileCpNavigationPage(Page root): base(root)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool IgnoreLayoutChange { get; set; } = false;

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            if (!IgnoreLayoutChange)
                base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the MasterDetailPage XAML:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MoblieCP.Pages"
             xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:MoblieCP.Utility"
             x:Class="MoblieCP.Pages.MainPage"
             utility:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             Title="Customer Portal"
             MasterBehavior="Popover"     
             >

  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:MenuPage BindingContext="{Binding MenuViewModel}" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage></ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Finally, here i put the NavigationPage into the Detail of the MasterDetail Page:

```
                navigationPage = new MobileCpNavigationPage(page);
                mainPage.Detail = navigationPage;
```

Comment: I test the code in the guide you provided with the master detail page, you use transparent toolbar only on detail page, and there is no operation to move the Hamburger icon on right side on my test. Please provide more details.

Comment: Shouldnt the movement of the Hamburger be handled by the MasterDetail page by itself ?
And i dont need the transparent toolbar in the Master page... only in the navigation page that sits in the Detail Page

Comment: If you mean the back icon, it is handled by the page self.

Comment: Ok , so what do i need to add in order for it to work ?

Comment: The Hamburger icon of master detail page is always on the left side. I want to know how do you open the drawer when the back icon appeared.